# Excel range to outlook email body with autofit

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I want to ask if it possible to autofit the excel range copied to email body? When it automatically paste/using code, excel range looks mess. But when I manually copied and paste it, it looks better.

Sample photo for auto-paste/using VBA: [USING VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmVlN.jpg)

Sample photo for manual (much better for me): [MANUALLY COPIED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Do9E.jpg)

Latest Update of my work:[LATEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI11M.jpg)

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    .Cells(1).EntireRow.AutoFit
    .Cells(1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit


'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile
Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Any suggestion for this? Thanks in advance. Btw, credits to Ron De Bruin for the codes.

Comment: I use almost the same function (credit to Ron de Bruin for min) EXCEPT without the following three lines that you have: `.Cells(1).EntireRow.AutoFit`, `.Cells(1).EntireColumn.AutoFit`  &   `TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit`.      I think the problem is using autofit on the entire row.      Perhaps delete the first two and add `TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.AutoFit` after the third one.

Comment: Still not working for me. Does too many columns in row may have affect of this? Because I have columns A:X.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference.   Perhaps take out the autofit lines altogether (which would match my code).   Alternatively you can add a breakpoint in the code at the autofit then step through the rest to follow what it is doing.

Comment: I've tried that before. Nothing happens. Still the same. I really don't know now what may cause or where should I edit for the fitting of cells.

Comment: I went back to your question and it looks like your preferred table has a lot of white space in each row above the cell values.   (I must have had both the sample images open and through you wanted a tight fitting table.) 

If you do want a lot of white space, why do you need autofit at all?   I did a test without it and the RangetoHMTL() gave an identical table to a manual copy and paste.  

Other than that you would have to post a sample of your source sheet.

Comment: Hi @tjejojyj, my work is already look like in the latest image I posted above.

Comment: Comparing the "latest" image and and the "much better" image, the differences seems to be the row height and the vertical alignment of the text.    If the source range is formatted as you want it to appear in the .HTMLBody and you have taken out the autofit lines, I really can't see by the RangeToHTML() wouldn't be working.   Sorry this isn't much help; I'm not sure what else to suggest.